# How to use iterativa data path in v-for loop (Vue)

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, v-for

I am a beginner of Vue
I would like to use my iterative image file name as "room1.jpg", "room2.jpg", "room3.jpg" ...

This is my code, the second line is the problem

```
  <div v-for="(p,i) in products" :key="i">
    <img src= "./assets/room"+str(i)+".jpg"  class = "room-img">
    <h4 @click="modelFlag = true">{{products[i]}}</h4>
    <p>{{prices[i]}}</p>
    <button @click="increase(i)">sign</button> 
  </div>
```

In Pyhton, I usually use for this

```
for i in range(number):
   "./assets/room"+str(i)+".jpg"
```

Is there any similar way to this?

Answer (score 0):

You've to bind variable data into your `src` as follow

```
  <div v-for="(p,i) in products" :key="i">
<img :src="`./assets/room${str(i)}.jpg`" class = "room-img">
<h4 @click="modelFlag = true">{{products[i]}}</h4>
<p>{{prices[i]}}</p>
<button @click="increase(i)">sign</button>
```

You can perform/do above as follow too:
`:src="'./assets/room'+str(i)+'.jpg'"`

And it will works.
`:src` and `v-bind:src` work in same way

Reference

https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-bind

Comment: I solve as     <img :src="require('./assets/room'+i+'.jpg')"  class = "room-img"> 'require' should be added for this

Comment: require is only need when you want to resolve your path using JS